# How to use multiple cores with sklearn dbscan?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, dask, dbscan

I'm trying to process a large volume of data through `dbscan` and would love to use all cores available to me on the machine to speed up the computation. I'm using a custom distance metric, but the distance matrix is not precomputed.

I have tried many different implementations, but have not had much success. I've listed them below, along with what I observed when tracking the performance with `top` in the terminal window.

1. Using the built-in `n_jobs` input:

```
model = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samps,metric=distance_sphere_and_time, n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(X)
```

The CPU only hits 2% usage. It looks like only one core of a possible 48 is included in the computation.

2. Using the built-in `n_jobs` input with the algorithm `Brute`.

```py
model = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samps,metric=distance_sphere_and_time, algorithm=`Brute`, n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(X)
```

It was suggested to be the only way `dbscan` works with parallel processing here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/8039, although there was a warning, the `Brute` could slow it down. The CPU usage hit 100%, but it was not faster.

3. Using dask for the parallel processing.

```
client = Client(processes=False, n_workers=8)
    model = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samps,metric=distance_sphere_and_time)
    with parallel_backend('dask'):
        model.fit(X)
```

This type of implementation was suggested here: https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial/issues/80. However, the CPU utilization remains at 2% suggesting that only one core is being used.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: As an update - I was able to increase the CPU utilization by removing the inputs in `Client` and adding `n_jobs=-1` to DBSCAN. I couldn't get it to use all the cores available, but did increase the CPU usage to about 35%.


`client = Client()`
`model = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samps, metric=distance_sphere_and_time, n_jobs=-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is python. Try the same in other tools such as ELKI (don't forget to add, e.g., a cover tree index) and you'll see a huge speed difference.

The reason is that your distance is a user function. The ball tree used by sklearn to search for neighbors is Cython, and for every distance computation it needs to go back to the interpreter. It even will *copy* the point data for every distance computation. These callbacks likely involve the infamous Python GIL, and hence ruin any parallelization efforts.

Answer (score 0):

-Using Dask parallel processing, `processes=False` tells dask to use multithreading instead of multiprocessing, which isn't recommended for GIL-invoking workflows. (Ref docs: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html)

So, you can use the following for better performance across all cores:
`client = Client(processes=True, n_workers=number_of_cpu_cores, threads_per_worker=1)`

Where `n_workers` equals the number of CPU cores you have, and `threads_per_worker=1`, tells dask to use one-process-with-one-thread per worker. Also note, that `processes=True` is the default configuration, so you needn't mention it explicitly.